# How to debug react-native app using reanimated and firebase

Tags: react-native, debugging, react-native-firebase, react-native-reanimated

native developers. I have been developing and maintaining a react-native app for the past four years now. Now I have come to a point where I no longer know a way to debug my app. I am using recent versions of both `react-native-reanimated` and `@react-native-firebase` for stability and feature requirements. Both of these libraries have limitations on debugging.

`react-native-reanimated` uses Turbo Modules and breaks debugging react-native with chrome tools and the great `react-native-debugger`.

`@react-native-firebase` above v15.x now requires us to have `use_frameworks!` in our Podfile which breaks Flipper debugging.

Without these options for debugging, what is left? Is anyone in the same situation and has a solution to debug their react-native app and view their redux state?

I appreciate the help.

My current versions in my app:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "15.5.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
```

Comment: Same situation and I’ve scoured the internet and it seems like a lot of people are stuck

Comment: Are you using Expo? You might be able to use the built-in debugging, but it's probably broken by the same issue because it's very similar to Flipper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this issue for a long time, the only thing I could do was to downgrade firebase to 14.x version.
So you have to use a version of `@react-native-firebase` before v15.x which requires `use_frameworks!`. I would suggest trying version `14.5.0`, which is the last minor version before 15.x. and the trade-off is not so big (so far). Let's hope, that before firebase introduces some breaking changes, the conflicting libraries will be optimised.

If you pick this approach:

1. It's important to note that this is a workaround and not the ideal solution
2. Remember to remove `use_frameworks!` from your podfile if you've added
   it previously

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging with [Reactotron.](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron)  It is a macOS, Windows, and Linux app for inspecting React JS and React Native apps.

Use it to:

- view your application state
- show API requests & responses
- perform quick performance benchmarks
- subscribe to parts of your application state
- display messages similar to `console.log`
- track global errors with source-mapped stack traces including saga stack traces!
- dispatch actions like a government-run mind control experiment
- hot swap your app's state using Redux or mobx-state-tree
- track your sagas
- show image overlay in React Native
- track your Async Storage in React Native

You plug it into your app as a dev dependency so it adds nothing to your product builds.

[Quick start for React Native](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/quick-start-react-native.md)